# C MACRO that dynamically use different defines

Tags: c, macros, arm, embedded

the purpose of the MACRO I'm trying to write is to update a char passing a new value defined by Value, position and length. Let me give you an example to better explain:

Original value      : 0b11000011
Value to update     : 0b11
Position to put     : 4
lenght to new value : 2

Basically I want to put two bits (0b11) in the middle of the byte (0b110**00**011) in order to have a new byte (0b110**11**011)

the MACRO I have right now is something like

```
#define UPDATE_REG(REG, MASK, POS, LEN, VAL) ((REG) = (((REG) & (MASK)) | (VAL<<(POS +1 -LEN))))
```

and it works well. For example, in my header I have definitions like

```
#define     CP_BYP_MODE_SAD                                     0x38
#define     CP_BYP_MODE_ADR                                     0xD4
#define     CP_BYP_MODE_POS                                     4
#define     CP_BYP_MODE_LEN                                     3
#define     CP_BYP_MODE_DEF                                     0b00
#define     CP_BYP_MODE_MSK                                     0b11100111
```

and to use the MACRO I write the following code

```
uint8_t Reg = 0b11000011;
UPDATE_REG(Reg, CP_BYP_MODE_MSK, CP_BYP_MODE_POS, CP_BYP_MODE_LEN, 0b11);
```

This solution works well but my point is that I'd like to reduce the arguments (if possible) with some tricks, considering that I'll use, for each call, three defines that are composed by 
name_MSK
name_POS
name_LEN

Just to be clear, my target is to have a MACRO something like

```
#define UPDATE_REG(REG, NAME, VAL) ((REG) = (((REG) & (**NAME_MSK**)) | (VAL<<(**NAME_POS** +1 - **NAME_LEN**))))
```

able to get, for example, CP_BYP_MODE_POS passing only CP_BYP_MODE and able to add automatically _POS suffix.

Comment: Are you aware of the `#` and `##` operators, which are most often used in macro-magic?

Comment: I tried to do something but I got some errors, due to the convertion between int (e.g. CP_BYP_MODE_POS and char). For sure I'm missing something

Comment: That's position 3 not 4. Bits are enumerated from zero and up, since we are using binary numbers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's really no need to write obscure macros for this, you'll only make the code harder to read. It is unfortunately common that people try to hide simple bit-wise arithmetic behind abstraction layers, just because they find bit-wise arithmetic tricky.

What you should do instead is to keep it simple:

```
uint8_t reg = 0xC3; 
uint8_t mask = 0x18;
uint8_t new_val = 0x18;
reg &= ~mask; // clear values with mask
reg |= new_val; // write new value to the cleared position
```

---

Notable, if you know the mask, that means you already know the size and bit position. You can calculate the mask based of size and position like this:

```
mask = ((1 << size)-1) << pos;
```

size = 2, pos = 3 gives:
`1 << 2` = 0000 0100b = 0x04
`0x04-1` = 0000 0011b = 0x03
`0x03 << 3` = 0001 1000b = 0x18

Comment: Sorry to rain a bit on your parade, but your example is rather an argument against coding bitwise manipulation explicitly. If `reg` happens to be a hardware register, the transient situation of `reg` with all 0s in the masked out bits may be an unacceptable, even bug-causing state. It is exactly for these cases why hiding the bit juggling behind macros is a sensible decision - an unexperienced engineer may spend days or weeks with bugs from seemingly error free and simulation-clean code.

Comment: @Vroomfondel When programming, you actually have to know what you are doing. If you are writing to a hardware register, without having read the manual to know how that register works, then _of course_ your program will go haywire. That's no fault of the bitwise operators or the C language, but a fault of the incompetent programmer.

Comment: Sorry, but I see that differently. Programming is an exercise in abstraction. Why burden the programmer with intrinsic and often simply by-convention details every time he accesses hardware, just because? And I dare saying that for at least five minutes a day, everyone of us is incompetent ;)

Comment: @Vroomfondel What you are saying is "let someone else write the hard parts of the program". Adding abstraction layers doesn't make hardware-related code go away. Someone must still write the driver and that person must know how the hardware works. The driver must still be there, even if the application-layer programmer doesn't need to know the implementation details of it in order to use it.

Comment: Um, no I don't say that. What I say is that once I have a working functional and generalizing description of something, I have a hard time seeing the advantage not to use it. In projects where there are >1 programmers with differing fields of expertise, this is even more important.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
/* this bitfield may appear in more places: */
#define TWO_BITS_FOR_ALICE 4,2 /*starting bit, length in bits*/

#define REG1_TWO_BITS_FOR_ALICE REG1,TWO_BITS_FOR_ALICE

/* this is a global bitfield, e.g. some unique hardware register: */
#define REG1_TWO_BITS_FOR_BOB   REG1,0,2 /*destination,starting bit,length in bits */

#define MASK_OUT(start,length) ~(MASK_IN((start),(length)))
#define MASK_IN(start,length) ((-1u<<(start))+(1u<<((start)+(length))))

#define SET_GBFLD(bfld,value) _SET_BFLD(bfld,value)
#define SET_BFLD(target,bfld,value) _SET_BFLD(target,bfld,value)
#define _SET_BFLD(target,start,length,value) ((target) = ((target)&MASK_OUT((start),(length))) | (((value) & MASK_IN(0,(length)))<<(start)))

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned REG1 = 0;
    SET_GBFLD(REG1_TWO_BITS_FOR_ALICE,7);
    SET_GBFLD(REG1_TWO_BITS_FOR_BOB,7);
    printf("%04x ",REG1);

    unsigned REG2 = 0;
    SET_BFLD(REG2,TWO_BITS_FOR_ALICE,7);
    printf("%04x ",REG2);
}
```